# Linq dynamic sorting on child properties

Tags: sorting, datatable, linq-to-entities

Based on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part) example, I'm able to apply sorting to parent record properties.  However I can't apply sorting to child records.

In the example, a delegate is created which sets the ordering on the Company properties:

```
Func<Company, string> orderingFunction = (c =>  sortColumnIndex == 1 ? c.Name :
                                                sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.Address :
                                                c.Town);
```

which is then applied to the resultset:

```
results = results.OrderBy(orderingFunction)
```

Now, say Company had child records, how would I go about using the same technique to sort on the child properties?

I tried something like this:

```
Func<ChildObject, string> orderingFunction = (c => c.ChildRecords.FirstOrDefault().SomeProperty );
```

and I tried applying the sorting directly to the resultset:

```
results = results.OrderBy(x => x.ChildRecords.OrderBy(c => c.SomeProperty))
```

Neither of these approaches work.

Comment: Your first approach will sort by the value of SomeProperty on the first ChildRecord of each Company. What is unsatisfactory about that approach?

Comment: @SteveRuble - It would be fine if Company only had one child record but there are multiple child records that need to be sorted, and as you say, only the first ChildRecord is being sorted using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason on why it's not working

```
Func<ChildObject, string> orderingFunction = (c => c.ChildRecords.FirstOrDefault().SomeProperty );
```

This code is not working because it's only take one child record.

```
results = results.OrderBy(x => x.ChildRecords.OrderBy(c =>
        c.SomeProperty))
```

This is not working because no matter you order bythe child record, it would always be ordered back by default based on the x criteria.

So, how to make it works?
If you want to order the list of the company, just simply put the logic ordering in the ordering function. Something like this.

```
    results = results.OrderBy(Function(m)
  If "Check custom logic to determine the order" Then
      Return 2
  Else
      Return 1
  End If
 End Function)
```

It is on VB.NET language. Apology for this. I am not sure about the syntax in C# but the idea is roughly like that.

For sample case, the class structures are as below:

```
            Parent p1 = new Parent
            {
                Name = "Test1",
                Index = "1",
                Children = new List<Child> { 
                    new Child {Name = "Child1", Index = "3"},
                    new Child {Name = "Child2", Index = "2"},
                    new Child {Name = "Child3", Index = "1"}
                }
            };

            Parent p2 = new Parent
            {
                Name = "Test2",
                Index = "2",
                Children = new List<Child> { 
                    new Child {Name = "Child4", Index = "6"},
                    new Child {Name = "Child5", Index = "5"},
                    new Child {Name = "Child6", Index = "4"}
                }
            };

            List<Parent> listParent = new List<Parent>();
            listParent.Add(p1);
            listParent.Add(p2);
```

So, what you want to achieve is to sort selected Child property?

I assume something like this? This would be able to order by based on the Child.

```
listParent.ForEach(x => {
    x.Children = x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Index).ToList();
});
listParent.ToList<Parent>().ForEach(x => x.Children.ToList<Child>().ForEach(y => Console.WriteLine(y.Name)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about why it's not working, but I'm having problems with the Linq syntax for selecting the sortable child property

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Please kindly refer to my comment above. So what you want to achieve is to sort selected Child Property?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I need to sort on a child property.  I tried your example and it nearly works - it sorts on the child property, but grouped by parent. I would like to sort by child property without the parent grouping.

Comment: I think it's not possible without doing a join between the two parent objects and afterwards sort the children. The function order by is to order the collection. As for the example, the order by function would do the ordering for Child collections in the parent. That's the reason why the child property is sorted but grouped by parent.